# Cassandra blob performance

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I have a use-case in which I receive properties in run-time from client in `JSON`.

e.g

- `{ ..., "pname" : "country", "value" : "USA", "ptype" : "String" }`
- `{ ..., "pname" : "gdp", "value" : 7.4 , "ptype" : "double"}`

Accourding to my use case I apply sum, min, max function on rows that have 
`"ptype" =  "double"` or `int`.

I have used this below Cassandra table to map my above request to cassandra table.

```
    create table IF NOT EXISTS kspace.count_table
    (source_id bigint, name varchar, date text, pname varchar, ptype varchar, pvalue blob, 
    count counter,unique_count counter, PRIMARY 
    KEY((source_id,name,pname,ptype,date),pvalue))
```

I have used `pvalue` as blob **because I receive properties of different data type from client in run time**.

My question is, is it good idea to use blob according to my use case or instead of blob should I use `String` and than parse each according to type.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes. It's a good Idea.**

You can insert ascii, bigint, boolean, decimal, double, float, inet, int, timestamp, timeuuid, uuid, varchar, varint into blob field.

It's memory efficient to insert double or int as blob, it will take only 32 bit for int and 64 bit for double. If you would have used ascii, will take 8 bit for each character, if you insert Integer max value (2147483647) it will take 80 bit.